# MVC and MVVM framework ViewModel part of which layer?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wpf, asp.net-mvc-4, mvvm

I am designing a application for desktop, web and mobile, and implementation MVVM (WPF) for desktop and MVC (ASP.Net MVC) for web. Can any one suggest me that ViewModel will be part of presentation layer or below to the services layer if services layer than ViewModel can be access through services layer only.

Comment: Generally your service layer is called from your ViewModel in a WPF application or your Controller (C or MVC) in your ASP.NET Application.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: In other words, they interpret user input into actions to be executed on the business layer.

Answer (score 1):

Based my understanding on your question . MVVM and MVC both belong to Presentation layer .

Service Layer will have service model , and will provide service model for WPF/MVC to convert into ViewModel through some auto mapper class.

on laying design point of view , you can take a look at below link :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658127.aspx

Comment: "MVC" doesn't _belong_ to the Presentation layer.  Specfically, `M` is your domain models, nothing to do with your presentation layer.